# how can I stop ggploty() adding lines between map points?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly, ggplotly

I'm using `plotly` package to convert my ggmap into HTML. However, after I apply `ggplotly()`, there are lines produced between map points. My df looks like:

`df <- data.frame("Name" = c("A", "A", "A", "B","B"),
                  "lat" = c(42.04614, 40.14664, 37.63910, 29.73602, 33.97907),
                  "lng" = c(-88.03842, -82.98982, -122.41923, -95.58586, -84.21856))`

And my code is:

```
map <- get_map(location = 'united states', zoom = 4, source = "google", color = "bw")
p <- ggmap(map) 
p <- p + geom_point(data = df, aes(x=lng, y=lat, group = Name, colour = Name))
plotly <- ggplotly(p)
```

With out `ggplotly()`, my map is:[image]

And after apply ggplotly(), my map turns to be :
[image]

How can I stop that? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: possibly leaflet is a easier way to go, since it accepts sf-objects.. You can then create a (poly)line-object with all the lines. read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50867215/leaflet-add-multiple-polylines/50870772#50870772

Comment: I think he wants points instead of lines in plotly @Wimpel

Comment: @Rishi you are right.. i misread :)

Comment: Your code gives me what you want. I am using `ggmap_2.6.1, plotly_4.7.1.9000, and ggplot2_2.2.1.9000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to other libraraies.
Here is an approach using leaflet.
Leaflet is an interactive approach to looking at maps, you can also add popups to the map which are accessed by clicking on the circles.

```
library(leaflet)
library(RColorBrewer)

mapper1 <- leaflet(df) %>%  
    addTiles() %>% 
    setView(lng=-95.7129, lat=37.0902, zoom=4)

pal = colorFactor(c("red","blue"), domain = df$Name)
color_incident = pal(df$Name) 

mpop <- mapper1 %>% addCircles(data = df, lat=~lat, lng= ~lng, color=color_incident)  %>% addLegend(pal=pal, values=~df$Name, title="Names")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help! and yes, I decided to change the package. :(