# How to create multiline string sf object to create a time slider in Leaflet map

Tags: mapping, r-sf, r-leaflet

I'm trying to create a leaflet map which shows different movement paths for different months of the year. I.e. I've got a dataset showing multiple journeys per month and I want to display the movement paths separately for each month using the addTimeslider feature of the leaflet.extras2 package.

To do so I have been trying to adapt the code posted by SymbolixAU I found here: [leaflet add multiple polylines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50867215/leaflet-add-multiple-polylines)

This code uses sf functions including st_linestring to create an object that can be supplied to a addPolylines leaflet function to show all movement paths at once.

I'm pretty sure for my purposes (showing data separately for each month) I have to use st_multilinestring, which takes a list of matrices containing the coordinates for multiple polylines per row (with one row per month) rather than a single polyline per row.

Once I have that I think I could supply that object to the addTimeslider function of leaflet.extras2 to achieve what I need. I'm quite sure of this because when I used the sf object created using sf_linestring inthe AddTimeslider feature I was able to use the time slider on the map to individual movement paths at a time.

However, I have been trying for hours and haven't been successful. Would be hugely grateful for any pointers, please and thank you.

Some example data:

```
#load packages

library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras2)
library(sf)
library(data.table)

# create the example dataset

data <- structure(list(arrival_month = structure(c(3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("January", "February", "March", 
"April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", 
"November", "December"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), start_lat = c(33.40693, 
33.64672, 33.57127, 33.42848, 33.54936, 33.53418, 33.60399, 33.49554, 
33.5056, 33.61696), start_long = c(-112.0298, -111.9255, -112.049, 
-112.0998, -112.0912, -112.0911, -111.9273, -111.9687, -112.0563, 
-111.9866), finish_lat...4 = c(33.40687, 33.64776, 33.57125, 
33.42853, 33.54893, 33.53488, 33.60401, 33.49647, 33.5056, 33.61654
), finish_lat...5 = c(-112.0343, -111.9303, -112.0481, -112.0993, 
-112.0912, -112.0911, -111.931, -111.9711, -112.0541, -111.986
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000026e5df41ef0>)
```

My attempt at the code:

```
# Convert the data into a list of matrices for each month

mnths <- c("May","March","April","June")


mat_list <- list()



for (i in mnths) {
  
  month <- as.matrix(data %>% filter(arrival_month == i) %>% select(-1)) 
  mat_list[[i]] <- month
  
}

# convert to an sf object


data_DT <- setDT(data)

sf <- data_DT[
  , {
    geometry <- sf::st_multilinestring(x = mat_list)
    geometry <- sf::st_sfc(geometry)
    geometry <- sf::st_sf(geometry = geometry)
  }
  , by = arrival_month
  ]

sf <- sf::st_as_sf(sf)
```

This yields the following result:

[image: sf]

It's not correct because each row contains the coordinates for all the months, rather than just for the month in the respective row. I'm at a loss as to where to go from here - any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it slightly differently today, making use of `{sfheaders}` to build the linestrings.

```r
library(sfheaders)
library(sf)
library(data.table)


setDT( data )

data[, line_id := .I ]  ## Assuming each row is a line

## create a long-form of the data
dt_line <- rbindlist(
  list(
    data[, .(arrival_month, line_id, lon = start_long, lat = start_lat, sequence = 1)]
    , data[, .(arrival_month, line_id, lon = finish_lat...5, lat = finish_lat...4, sequence = 2)] ## I think 'finish_lat...5' is actually the 'long' 
  )
)

setorder(dt_line, line_id, sequence)

sf <- sfheaders::sf_multilinestring(
  obj = dt_line
  , x = "lon"
  , y = "lat"
  , multilinestring_id = "arrival_month"
  , linestring_id = "line_id"
  , keep = T
)

sf::st_crs( sf ) <- 4326 ## Assuming it's in Web Mercator 

# Simple feature collection with 4 features and 2 fields
# Geometry type: MULTILINESTRING
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -112.0998 ymin: 33.40687 xmax: -111.9255 ymax: 33.64776
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#.  arrival_month sequence                       geometry
# 1             3        1 MULTILINESTRING ((-112.0298...
# 2             4        1 MULTILINESTRING ((-112.049 ...
# 3             5        1 MULTILINESTRING ((-112.0911...
# 4             6        1 MULTILINESTRING ((-111.9687...
```

---

**Note** the `arrival_month` has been re-coded to it's factor levels.

Comment: Thanks for this. But it doesn't help with my problem - I likely didn't explain it well. What I need is a multiline string sf object which shows ALL the data for each month in a single row. E.g. if there are two movement paths for April, I want both to be displayed on the map at once.  The solution above only shows only single movement paths at a time. I almost get what I need if I assign each month the same idx in the data table, e.g. all March rows = 1, all May rows 2, etc. - this shows all the lines for a given month at once, but all the lines are joined up when they should be independent

Comment: I might be horribly wrong but I think the geometry column should look something like this, e.g. for a month with two lines/movement paths: c( lat, long, lat long), c(lat, long, lat, long), rather than c(lat, long, lat, long, lat, long, lat, long)

Comment: @Biased_Observer - please see my edit where I now use `sf_multilinestring()`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to adapt the code provided by SymbolixAU to suit my purposes, by using sf_multilinestring instead of sf_line string:

```
## Generate data

data <- structure(list(arrival_month = structure(c(3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("January", "February", "March", 
"April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", 
"November", "December"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), start_lat = c(33.40693, 
33.64672, 33.57127, 33.42848, 33.54936, 33.53418, 33.60399, 33.49554, 
33.5056, 33.61696), start_long = c(-112.0298, -111.9255, -112.049, 
-112.0998, -112.0912, -112.0911, -111.9273, -111.9687, -112.0563, 
-111.9866), finish_lat...4 = c(33.40687, 33.64776, 33.57125, 
33.42853, 33.54893, 33.53488, 33.60401, 33.49647, 33.5056, 33.61654
), finish_lat...5 = c(-112.0343, -111.9303, -112.0481, -112.0993, 
-112.0912, -112.0911, -111.931, -111.9711, -112.0541, -111.986
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
))

## Add id column and convert to data table

data[, line_id := .I ]

setDT(data)

## create a long-form of the data

dt_line <- rbindlist(
  list(
    data[, .(arrival_month, line_id, lon = start_long, lat = start_lat, sequence = 1)]
    , data[, .(arrival_month, line_id, lon = finish_lat...5, lat = finish_lat...4, sequence = 2)] ## I think 'finish_lat...5' is actually the 'long' 
  )
)

setorder(dt_line, line_id, sequence)

## Create multistring sf object

sf <- sfheaders::sf_multilinestring(
  obj = dt_line
  , x = "lon"
  , y = "lat"
  , linestring_id = "line_id"
  , multilinestring_id = "arrival_month"
  , keep = TRUE
)

sf::st_as_sf(sf)

## Convert arrival_month back to factor

sf$arrival_month <- as.factor(sf$arrival_month)
```

Might not be the most elegant but this does the job.

The key was to use sf_multilinestring and include/specify both linestring_id and multilinestring_id to distinguish between separate sets of polylines.

This is the result:

[image: resulting sf object]

Now when this sf object is used in AddTimeslider it behaves as desired.

Credit to SymbolixAU for most of the code and bringing my attention to the sfheaders package